# How to receive data through websockets in python

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to retrieve data programmatically through websockets and am failing due to my limited knowledge around this. On visiting the site at https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=ASX:RIO  I notice one of the websocket messages being sent out is `~m~60~m~{"m":"quote_fast_symbols","p":["qs_p089dyse9tcu","ASX:RIO"]}`

My code is as follows:

```
from websocket import create_connection
import json 

ws = create_connection("wss://data.tradingview.com/socket.io/websocket?from=chart%2Fg0l68xay%2F&date=2019_05_27-12_19")

ws.send(json.dumps({"m":"quote_fast_symbols","p"["qs_p089dyse9tcu","ASX:RIO"]}))
result =  ws.recv()
print(result)
ws.close()
```

Result of the print:

```
~m~302~m~{"session_id":"<0.25981.2547>_nyc2-charts-3-webchart-5@nyc2-compute-3_x","timestamp":1558976872,"release":"registry:5000/tvbs_release/webchart:release_201-106","studies_metadata_hash":"888cd442d24cef23a176f3b4584ebf48285fc1cd","protocol":"json","javastudies":"javastudies-3.44_955","auth_scheme_vsn":2}
```

I get this result no matter what message I send out, out of the almost multitude of messages that seem to be sent out. I was hoping one of the messages sent back will be the prices info for the low and highs for RIO. Is there other steps I should include to get this data? I understand there might be some form of authorisation needed but I dont know the workflow.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? I've been trying for a few weeks now to figure out how to capture information.

Comment: @tomoc4 There’s a variety of other sites with this trading data that dont use web sockets so I simply ignored tradingview. Was working on someones project and I think we ended up using cmcmarkets

Comment: If you really wanted to get it working in python I guess you could try to analyse how other scripts implement this. I seen a few nodejs examples on github with a google search

Comment: Thanks for this. Would using selenium and a gecko webdriver interacting with the site get the websocket delivered data? That was what I was planning to try next. The metrics they have are really useful but really difficult to scrape.

Comment: No worries. What other metrics are you trying to get? If you using selenium then you can get all the data easily that isnt in the chart. Not sure but as for websockets I dont think what you get will be much useful in its raw form as i think its just data used to build the charts so wont be straightforward open and close prices.

Comment: I'm not actually looking for chart data. I've scraped all the financials section and latest news story. I'm then getting the scraping bot to select the technicals page on the stock and I want to get the buying signal arrow and all the metrics from that page. I'm more interested in the buying signal. Want to look at strong buys and measure performance after stock has been listed as a strong buy. The arrow doesn't have text so I need to use some sort of regex to parse the div class name in order to store what the arrow means. Using scrapy/splash and lua script to do this

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is much more to setup and it needs to be done in order. The following example written in **Node.js** will subscribe to the **BINANCE:BTCUSDT** real time data and fetch historical **5000** bars on the daily chart.

1. Ensure you have proper value of the **origin** field set in **header** section before connecting. Otherwise your connection request will be rejected by the proxy. I most common `ws` there is no way to do this. Use `faye-websocket` instead

```js
const  WebSocket = require('faye-websocket')  

const  ws = new  WebSocket.Client('wss://data.tradingview.com/socket.io/websocket', [], {
  headers: { 'Origin':  'https://data.tradingview.com' }
});
```

2. After connecting you need to setup your data stream. I don't know if all of this commands needs to be performed. This probably can be shrink even more but it works. Basically what you need to do is to create new quote and chart sessions and within these sessions request stream of the data of the prior resolved symbol.

```js
ws.on('open', () => {

  const  quote_session = 'qs_' + getRandomToken()
  const  chart_session = 'cs_' + getRandomToken()
  const  symbol = 'BINANCE:BTCUSDT'
  const  timeframe = '1D'
  const  bars = 5000

  sendMsg(ws, "set_auth_token", ["unauthorized_user_token"])
  sendMsg(ws, "chart_create_session", [chart_session, ""])
  sendMsg(ws, "quote_create_session", [quote_session])
  sendMsg(ws, "quote_set_fields", [quote_session,"ch","chp","current_session","description","local_description","language","exchange","fractional","is_tradable","lp","lp_time","minmov","minmove2","original_name","pricescale","pro_name","short_name","type","update_mode","volume","currency_code","rchp","rtc"])
  sendMsg(ws, "quote_add_symbols",[quote_session, symbol, {"flags":['force_permission']}])
  sendMsg(ws, "quote_fast_symbols", [quote_session, symbol])
  sendMsg(ws, "resolve_symbol", [chart_session,"symbol_1","={\"symbol\":\""+symbol+"\",\"adjustment\":\"splits\",\"session\":\"extended\"}"])
  sendMsg(ws, "create_series", [chart_session, "s1", "s1", "symbol_1", timeframe, bars])

});

ws.on('message', (msg) => { console.log(`RX: ${msg.data}`) })
```

3. And finally implementation of the helper methods

```js
const  getRandomToken = (stringLength=12) => {
  characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
  const  charactersLength = characters.length;
  let  result = ''
  for ( var  i = 0; i < stringLength; i++ ) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength))
  }
  return  result
}

const  createMsg = (msg_name, paramsList) => {
  const  msg_str = JSON.stringify({ m:  msg_name, p:  paramsList })
  return  `~m~${msg_str.length}~m~${msg_str}`
}

const  sendMsg = (ws, msg_name, paramsList) => {
  const  msg = createMsg(msg_name, paramsList)
  console.log(`TX: ${msg}`)
  ws.send(createMsg(msg_name, paramsList))
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @Paweł Zalewski, I know it's an old topic, but have you been able to fetch the data from a study or indicator through the socket? The data clearly comes thru that way, BUT I can't figure a way to ping the socket to return it. Doing so requires sending a "create_study" message containing a "text" field which rotates every session... seems an encrypted/hashed message. Any luck figuring this one out?